# Receive Json In Foreign Language(For Example Russian) Android

Tags: android, json, parsing

Good Day Guys. I am trying to receive some `JSON` which is written in Russian and might have to receive in Chinese too, mainly lets say worldwide. So any language letters i must receive in `JSON`.

Problem is that when I receive `JSON` which should look like

```
{
    "file_path":"storage\/paqstorage/paq/1278/1432230404Lighthouse - копия-копия-копия.jpg",
    "file_id":"376"
}
```

But when I parse the string, it looks like

```
{
    "file_path":"storage\/paq\/1278\/1432230404Lighthouse - \u043a\u043e\u043f\u0438\u044f.jpg",
    "file_id":"376"
}
```

I am using the following code to parse the `JSON` data

```
JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("files");
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
    stringArrayList.add(o.getString("file_path"));
}
```

I tried `UTF8` and `ISO` encoding of string but nothing helped. They all giving me same value. So my question is, is that a problem of mine or should server part already sent me encoded string? or should I encode string of specific language?

Comment: What you are seeing is unicode characters. You need to set your logcat encoding to utf-8.

Comment: If that's not the case then you need to handle this on Server side. Save your script file as Utf-8 encoding and there is also a code i used (i don't remember now). Will try to find and post here if found.

Comment: Here you go use this function `function replace_unicode_escape_sequence($match) { return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $match[1]), 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2BE');` like this `preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})/i', 'replace_unicode_escape_sequence', $json);` also you may need to save your script file as UTF-8 encoded! `

Answer (score 0):

There could be two scenarios for such problem. 
1. Your server-side script file is returning data in `Unicode` encoding. 
2. Only `Logcat` is rendering in Unicode encoding.

For 1 you need to write a small function in your script file + save the file as `UTF-8 encoding`. Please note following code only works for PHP.

```
function replace_unicode_escape_sequence($match) { return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $match[1]), 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2BE');
```

then call it like

```
preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})/i', 'replace_unicode_escape_sequence', $json);
```